# use doSNOW to speed up explicit loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

The computer I used in office has been recently upgraded to a quad-core one, which is a blessing to me, as sometimes I need to do some explicit loops using R, which the outcomes are based one some logical rules, which I can't figure out how to work this out other than a explicit loop.

For some background information, sometimes I have about 10000-20000 rows, which I need to look at 2 column, and base on their values and some logical rules, to generate value for a new column.

I am trying to use the `doSNOW` package to better utilize the unused CPU power, I have written a demo script as below, based on the example from [here](http://decisionstats.com/2010/09/24/parallel-programming-using-r-in-windows/):

```
library(doSNOW)
# rm(list=ls())

cl<-makeCluster(2) # I have two cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)

table <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1000),b=rnorm(1000))

process <- function(table)
              {for (loop in (1:nrow(table)))
                   {table[loop,"c"] <- with(table[loop,], a*b)
                    assign("table",table,envir=.GlobalEnv)
                   }
              }


system.time(process(table))

system.time(foreach(j=1:2 ) %dopar% process(table))

stopCluster(cl)
```

I am using a netbook with ATOM CPU inside to try this out, but the result is weird:

```
system.time(process(table))
user  system elapsed 
2.336   0.028   2.308 

system.time(foreach(j=1:2 ) %dopar% process(table))
user  system elapsed 
0.160   0.032   3.646
```

After using doSNOW, time needed for result is even longer than without using doSNOW, I wonder if this is the problem of my ATOM netbook, or did I make anything wrong in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but what parallel backend are you using (e.g. MPI)?

Comment: Just looked over your code.  **Never** put `rm(list=ls())` in a code sample on here, unless you want to make a lot of people *really* unhappy.

Comment: Is this the real function you are trying to optimise? If so, you'd be far better off writing it in a vectorised manner. Tip: I you're using assign the chances are you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm a big fan of snowfall package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html). It's super easy to use it. You write your function in apply form, initiate the cluster and run your function using snow(fall) apply versions (e.g. sfLapply). The vignette documents this well: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/vignettes/snowfall.pdf

Comment: What's the difference between doSnow and Snowfall?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, in your example you run the function once without `snow`, and twice with `snow`.  There is an added overhead in running processes in parallel, especially when you add the infrastructure of `foreach`.  So the average time per execution is less than if you ran them serially, but you can't expect the same overall time when you split things up.

So you are incorrect in saying "result is even longer than without using doSNOW".  In fact, if you ran the first one twice, it would take almost twice as long.  So `snow` has indeed improved the performance.

This is a fair comparison:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:2) process(table))
system.time(foreach(j=1:2 ) %dopar% process(table))
```

Think of it this way: suppose you have two people who can each independently do a task in 1 minute.  Let's assume that if one person does multiple tasks, there is additional overhead.  But if you ask them to work independently, it takes a little longer for them assemble their results together.  If you ask one person to do two tasks, it will take 2 minutes.  If you ask each person to work separately, then it will take a little more than 1 minute in total because they need to communicate at the end.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, on one machine it is better to use multicore than snow; it takes advantage of the fact pipes can be used instead of sockets, also the time needed to fork is smaller than to init new process.

Now, this is also why the parallel version worked longer on your netbook; there is an inevitable time cost of switching to parallel evaluation and it can dominate the gain from several threads. With longer jobs, this time would become negligible and you'll gain speedup.

Comment: i wished to use multicore, but I am using WinXP machine, which `doMC` package is not available

Comment: You can use doSMP on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason for the slowdown could also be due to the fact that you are most likely using a single core CPU (unless you have a newer dual-core Atom). In that case, you are are running R serially as you would without the foreach() function, but with some added overhead from the process trying to run in parallel. My suggestion is try it on the one in your office to see what happens there.